# The value of two integers $a$ and $b$

Tags: number-theory

I want to find two integers $ a $ and $ b $ which satisfies the following constraint .

1. $\gcd(a, b) = 1$
2. $0 < a/b < 1$
3. $a * b = (n!) ^ {n!}$.

I will be given the value of $n$ . I have to find the value of $ a $ and $ b $ . The value of $n$ can be very big .

I have to tell the number of fractions $ \frac{a}{b} $ for every value of n that satisfies the above equations . This number may be very large, so  the answer that have to provided by me is no_of_fraction modulo 10,007.

Answer (score 5):

Why don´t you just take $a=1$ and $b=n!^{n!}$?

Comment: Please see the question again .

Comment: Please note that this answers the question as asked originally (which was to find $a$ and $b$), not as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_n$ be the set of primes that are at most $n$.

**Hint:** For $p \in P_n$, if $p \mid a$, then $p \not \mid b$.

**Hint:** For $p \in P_n$, if $p \not \mid a$, then $p \mid b$.

**Hint:** Ignore the condition that $ 0 < a/b < 1 $ for now. There are (fill in the blank) pairs.

Hence, accounting for the condition, there are (fill in the blank) pairs.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this in a regular manner ?

Comment: @Waytoinfinity Which part are you stuck at? What do you not understand? There is more than enough for you to work it out, I don't believe in spoon-feeding.

Comment: Can you plz explain this problem for n = 1000 ?